# Planning Large Projects?

Tags: project-management

How do you start planning a fairly large project?  Do you immediately start writing up the major classes and break it down further and further? Do you sit down and draw out some UML?

I'm designing my first large project (well, large compared to the other ones) and I'm looking for ideas.

Comment: Google for "site:stackoverflow.com planning large project"

Comment: By large, do you mean it'll take decades to finish or just a few more months than your usual ones?

Comment: I would add: large in terms of duration, or large in terms of team size?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reading about agile methodology and scrum.

Answer (score 0):

Large Projects would be beneficial when used Agile scrum methodology.

1. Agile methods divides your projects into smaller sprints giving one the time to prioritize the main features to be concentrated & completed.
2. Continuous interaction with client means less ambiguity, more real value. The client would see live ideas before final. So more improvising at very early stage with ample of time to make it better.
3. Bug fixing process gets speedy. Less the bugs, more efficient the Project!
4. By using time-boxed, fixed schedule Sprints of 1-4 weeks, new features are delivered quickly and frequently, with a high level of predictability. This also provides the opportunity to release or beta test the software earlier than planned if there is sufficient business value.
5. Improves Quality. By breaking down the project into manageable units, the project team can focus on high-quality development, testing, and collaboration. Also, by producing frequent builds and conducting testing and reviews during each iteration, quality is improved by finding and fixing defects quickly and identifying expectation mismatches early.